# View controller and storyboards are not linking

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have two storyboard files, and one view controller that I would like them to share. On one storyboard everything works perfectly, but on the other it is not linking. When it loads it's just the buttons and stuff that do nothing when I click on them, and in the interface builder I can't link them because they're not showing up. So I've come to the conclusion that my files aren't linking correctly. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you set your view controller as the class in the storyboard that isn't working?

Comment: Oh my goodness I could've sworn I had checked that, but I guess not, yes it was that, thank you